# Implement multiple bouncing balls

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've messed around with Java a little bit and I decided to take a course to learn some more and I have been assigned a fairly easy assignment. I have it mostly done and I know what's left must be simple, but I cannot seem to quite get it. So far I have been able to successfully create a program that has 1 bouncing ball, but I would now like to allow the user to input the amount of balls to bounce. I have tried a few different loops in my Ball class, but none of them work. Would anyone be willing to give a quick hand? I am almost sure it would require either an Array or ArrayList and just storing the balls in it but I have yet to find a solution that works. I have looked at other problems like this on the website but none have quite solved my problem. Thank you if you can help!

Main Class :

```
public class mainClass {

    /**
    /**
   * Frame to hold a bouncing ball panel, implemented in the BallPanel class.
   * Controls the animation of the ball via pauses and calls to BallPanel's move
   * method.
   *
   * @author Michael Peterson modified by Mr O Aug 2012
   */
  public static class BallTest extends JFrame {

    // size of the window
    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300;
    // panel containing the bouncing ball
    private BallPanel ballPanel;

    /**
     * Pause command used to control the speed of the bouncing ball animation.
     * Currently pauses for 20 ms. Use smaller values for faster animation and
     * vice versa.
     */
    public static void pause() {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(20); // pause for 20 ms
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
      }//end of catch
    }//end of pause method 

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of BallTest
     */
    public BallTest() {
      super("Bouncing Ball");  // set frame name
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      ballPanel = new BallPanel();

      add(ballPanel);
      center(this);
      setVisible(true);

      // infinite animation loop, program halts when window is closed.
      while (true) {
        pause();
        ballPanel.move(ballPanel);
      }//end of while loop of animation        
    } //end of BallTest Constructor 

    /**
     * Helper routine to center a frame on the screen (will cause problems if
     * frame is bigger than the screen!)
     */
    public static void center(JFrame frame) {
      GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
      Point center = ge.getCenterPoint();

      int w = frame.getWidth();
      int h = frame.getHeight();

      int x = center.x - w / 2, y = center.y - h / 2;
      frame.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
      frame.validate();
    }//end of center method  
  }//end of BallPanel Class

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BallTest t = new BallTest(); //make a BallTest object
  }//end of main method
}//end of Fall2012Lab11StarterCode class
```

Ball Class :

```
public  class  Ball extends JPanel  {

  private int bxCoord;        //the ball's x coordinate
  private int byCoord;        //the ball's y coordinate
  private int bHeight;        //the ball's height
  private int bWidth;         //the ball's weight
  private int bRise;          //the ball's y change
  private int bRun;           //the ball's x change
  private Color bColor;       //the ball's color

//Constructor
  public Ball() {
    bxCoord = setStartBxCoord();
    byCoord = setStartByCoord();
    bHeight = setStartBHeight();
    bWidth = setStartBWidth();
    bRise = setStartBRise();
    bRun = setStartBRun();
    bColor = setStartColor();
  }

/**
 * The setters, getters, and initial value for the ball's x coordinate 
 */
  public void setBxCoord(int xCoord) {
    bxCoord = xCoord;
  }

  public int setStartBxCoord() {
    int xCoord;
    xCoord = (int) (Math.random() * 51);
    return xCoord;
  }

  public int getBxCoord() {
    return bxCoord;
  }

  /**
 * The setters, getters, and initial value for the ball's y coordinate 
 */
  public void setByCoord(int yCoord) {
    bxCoord = yCoord;
  }

  public int setStartByCoord() {
    int yCoord;
    yCoord = (int) (Math.random() * 51);
    return yCoord;
  }

  public int getByCoord() {
    return byCoord;
  }

  /**
 * The setters, getters, and initial value for the ball's x height 
 */
  public void setBHeight(int height) {
    bHeight = height;
  }

  public int setStartBHeight() {
    int height;
    height = (int) (10 + Math.random() * 11);
    return height;
  }

  public int getBHeight() {
    return bHeight;
  }

  public void setBWidth(int width) {
    bWidth = width;
  }

  /**
 * The setters, getters, and initial value for the ball's x width 
 */
  public int setStartBWidth() {
    int width;
    width = (int) (10 + Math.random() * 11);
    return width;
  }

  public int getBWidth() {
    return bWidth;
  }

  /**
 * The setters, getters, and initial value for the ball's rise 
 */
  public void setBRise(int rise) {
    bRise = rise;
  }

  public int setStartBRise() {
    int rise;
    rise = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
    return rise;
  }

  public int getBRise() {
    return bRise;
  }

  /**
 * The setters, getters, and initial value for the ball's run 
 */
  public void setBRun(int run) {
    bRun = run;
  }

  public int setStartBRun() {
    int run;
    run = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
    return run;
  }

  public int getBRun() {
    return bRun;
  }

  /**
   * The movement of the ball in the x and y direction
   */
  public void moveX(){

    bxCoord += bRun;    
  }

  public void moveY(){
    byCoord +=   bRise;
  }

 /**
 * The setters, getters, and initial value for the ball's color 
 */
  public void setColor(Color color) {
    bColor = color;
  }

  public Color setStartColor() {
    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    Color ranColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
    return ranColor;
  }

  public Color getbColor() {
    return bColor;
  }
    /**
   * Computes the next position for the balls and updates their positions.
   */
    public void move(BallPanel ballPanel) {
    // If ball is approaching a wall, reverse direction
    if ((getBxCoord() < (0  - getBRun())) || (getBxCoord() > (ballPanel.getWidth() - getBWidth()))) {
      setBRun(-getBRun());
    }
    if ((getByCoord() < (0 - getBRise())) || (getByCoord() > (ballPanel.getHeight() - getBHeight()))) {
      setBRise(-getBRise());
    }
    // "Move" ball according to values in rise and run
    moveX();
    moveY();
  } // end method move
}//end of Ball Class
```

Ball Panel Class :

```
public class BallPanel extends JPanel {

  Ball ball = new Ball();  //creat a ball.

  /**
   * Creates a new instance of BallPanel
   */
  public BallPanel() {
    super();
  }
/**
 * The move method moves the ball and repaints the panel
 * PreCondtion: A panel containing a ball has been created
 * PostCondition: The position of a ball on the panel has moved.  The panell
 * is repainted with the ball in the new position.
 * @param ballPanel The name of the panel on which the ball is found
 */
  public void move(BallPanel ballPanel) {
    ball.move(ballPanel);
    repaint();
  }

 /**
  * Paints the balls at their current positions within the panel.
  * PreCondition: A graphics object has been created and needs to be displayed 
  * PostCondition: The graphics object g has been displayed
  * @param g The graphic object to be displayed
  */
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
       g.setColor(Color.black);                         // set color black
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // paint background
    // Paint the Ball
    g.setColor(ball.getbColor());
    g.fillOval(ball.getBxCoord(), ball.getByCoord(),
            ball.getBWidth(), ball.getBHeight());
  }//end of paintComponent method
}//end of BallPanel class
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm answering you purely on previous codes i have done similar to this, because I didn't have the time to test out yours.

Your ballPanel class should look something more like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class BallPanel extends JPanel{
    private ArrayList<Ball> BallList = new ArrayList<Ball>();
    private int num;
    public BallPanel(int numberOfBalls){
        super();
        num = numberOfBalls;
        for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){BallList.add(new Ball());}
    }

    //the rest of your methods, using for loops for the balls
```

Also I think you can use this instead of ArrayList (this is easier):

```
Ball[] BallList = new Ball[numberOfBalls];
```

then an example of your move method should look like this:

```
public void move(BallPanel ballPanel){
    for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){
        BallList[i].move(ballPanel);
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issues with a Bouncing Ball program.  Tried the previously posted code, but the public void move(BallPanel area isn't working.  When I access an array in that location the ball stops moving.  Here is my current code for move:

```
public void move(BallPanel ballPanel, ArrayList<Ball> ballList) {

  for(int i = 0; i<1; i++){
      System.out.println("mmm" + i);
      ballList.get(i).move(ballPanel);
  }

  repaint();
```

Secondly as shown the paintComponent area above, only ball is used to paint the ball.  Is that OK that paintComponent is called multiple times but only has a variable ball in it.  Here is what that section looks like:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   g.setColor(Color.black);                         // set color black
   g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // paint background

// Paint the Ball
   g.setColor(ball.getbColor());
   g.fillOval(ball.getBxCoord(), ball.getByCoord(),
        ball.getBWidth(), ball.getBHeight());
```

Comment: How does this answer the question ?